# Web browser to preserve forward and backward history in a tree-like format

Tags: web-browser

I'm looking for a web browser which lets me view the link that I went to, before I clicked back and went to another page.

So for example:

- I navigate to page A
- on that page, I click link B
- I click back, going back to page A
- I click on link C

Link B (unless I find it again) is permanently inaccessible in the forward/back buttons, no matter how often I press back or forward.

I'm looking for a web browser (or addon) that would operate similar to [Vim's undo branches](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_undo_branches), and allow me to view or see that link again.

Answer (score 2):

[Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/new/) with the [History in Threads extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/history-in-threads/) will do exactly what you desire.

With this combination of software, you can see every page you visited, in a convenient tree format.

[image: History in Threads example]

*Image credit: Mozilla*